# Projecting GOES-16 Geostationary data into Plate Carree Cartopy

Tags: python, netcdf, cartopy

I am trying desperately to project some geostationary data from GOES-16 netCDF file to a different projection. I can get the background map to re-project but can't seem to get the data to follow.

I'm not super versed in this yet, but here is what I have thus far:

Reading the data through NetCDF4:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
nc = Dataset('OR_ABI-L1b-RadF- 
    M3C13_G16_s20182831030383_e20182831041161_c20182831041217.nc')

data = nc.variables['Rad'][:]
```

Here I'm trying to get the geostationary info:

```
sat_h = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].perspective_point_height
X = nc.variables['x'][:] * sat_h
Y = nc.variables['y'][:] * sat_h

# Satellite longitude
sat_lon = 
    nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].longitude_of_projection_origin

# Satellite sweep
sat_sweep = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection'].sweep_angle_axis
```

Here I'm taking projection data from the .nc file:

```
proj_var = nc.variables['goes_imager_projection']

sat_height = proj_var.perspective_point_height
central_lon = proj_var.longitude_of_projection_origin
semi_major = proj_var.semi_major_axis
semi_minor = proj_var.semi_minor_axis
print proj_var

<type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int32 goes_imager_projection()
    long_name: GOES-R ABI fixed grid projection
    grid_mapping_name: geostationary
    perspective_point_height: 35786023.0
    semi_major_axis: 6378137.0
    semi_minor_axis: 6356752.31414
    inverse_flattening: 298.2572221
    latitude_of_projection_origin: 0.0
    longitude_of_projection_origin: -75.0
    sweep_angle_axis: x
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = ()
filling on, default _FillValue of -2147483647 used
```

And here is a small snippet of my code that's relevant:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))

globe = ccrs.Globe(semimajor_axis=semi_major, semiminor_axis=semi_minor)
proj = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=central_lon, 
    satellite_height=sat_height, globe=globe)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)

IR_img = ax.imshow(data[:,:],origin='upper',extent=(X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()),
    cmap=IR_cmap,interpolation='nearest',vmin=162.,vmax=330.)
```

And an image of everyone playing nicely:
[Data and map working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hegJs.png)

When I try and get say a Plate Carree projection I try:

```
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=central_lon,globe=globe)
```

And an image of my failure:
[Data and map not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL1IS.png)

I've tried messing with the extent in the imshow method, I've tried adding a

```
transform=proj
```

in the imshow and no luck, it just gets hung up and I have to restart the kernel.

Clearly it is a lack of understanding on my part. If anyone can quickly and easily help/explain the way I want to change my projection from geostationary, I would greatly appreciate that.

I'm running archaic python2.

Thanks for looking.

EDIT: Problem seems to be resolved thanks to insight from DopplerShift and ajdawson, I guess I was maybe a little impatient/ignorant of how long a full disk transformation would take.

Comment: Are you sure it gets hung up when you pass in transform=proj? The full disk image you're using is *really* large and image warping in Cartopy can be pretty compute intensive. I bet this operation could easily take between 10 minutes and an hour.

Comment: I did think about that, but I'm pretty sure when I tried a subset of the data it would sit for a while and I couldn't just do a keyboard interrupt so I assumed it was totally hung up. I tried again this morning with a CONUS lat/lon ax.extent and it seems to run in a handful of seconds now. Thanks for the input as always DopplerShift, you've helped me out on a number of occasions.

Comment: @MethaneClouds I've run into the same issue. Can you expand on what your final solution looked like that ran in a handful of seconds? or are you saying that the full disk transform simply takes forever and you basically just switched to CONUS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to specify the transform keyword to imshow. This keyword tells cartopy what coordinates your data are in, which in this case should be geostationary.

I don't have your dataset so I cannot test this, but the snippet below illustrates the concept. The projection and the transform are independent so you should define both. The value of the transform argument (`crs` in the example below) is fixed for the data set, but the projection can be anything you like (including the same as `crs`).

See this example of reprojecting a geostationary image: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.16/gallery/geostationary.html#sphx-glr-gallery-geostationary-py. Also see the guide to projection and transform arguments here: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.16/tutorials/understanding_transform.html.

```
globe = ccrs.Globe(semimajor_axis=semi_major, semiminor_axis=semi_minor)
crs = ccrs.Geostationary(central_longitude=central_lon, 
                         satellite_height=sat_height, globe=globe)
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=central_lon, globe=globe)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=proj)

IR_img = ax.imshow(data[:,:], origin='upper',
                   extent=(X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()),
                   transform=crs,
                   cmap=IR_cmap,
                   interpolation='nearest', vmin=162., vmax=330.)
```

Comment: I tried that as well and still get the kernel freezing up. It must have something to do with my python setup as I've tried exactly what you suggested, even before asking the question here...